# Iterating over a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to complete some code for an homework.

It involves (among other things) iterating over a vector and I'm getting a strange result.

main.cpp

```
#include "tp1.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::vector<uint8_t> signal { 1,2,0,0,1,2,1,0,2,1,2,1,0,0,0,1,2,1 };
    std::vector<LZ77Code> code = lz77_encode(signal, 18, 9);

    return 0;
}
```

tp1.hpp

```
inline std::vector<LZ77Code> lz77_encode(const std::vector<uint8_t>& vSignal, size_t N, size_t n1) {

    std::vector<LZ77Code> vCode;

    std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator vSignalIt; //Iterator for the vector in the parameters

    vSignalIt = vSignal.begin();
    while (vSignalIt != vSignal.end())
    {
        std::cout << *vSignalIt << std::endl; 
        vSignalIt++;
    }

    return vCode;
}
```

I'm getting this printed in the console as a result :

```
☺
```

Not really what I intended, you guessed it. I shortened the code to the bare minimum because It's been a while since I dealt with C++ and I feel like I'm making a trivial error. Let me know if you need more details.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Not getting what you're getting. You should have an infinite loop because `vSignalIt` is never incremented

Comment: It is, I just forgot the part where I increment it. Editing right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `uint8_t` to `cout`, it treats it as a `char`. You need to cast to `int`.

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(*vSignalIt) << std::endl;
```

Comment: In general `uint8_t` may or may not be a character type, so good code needs to allow for both possibilities.